# use typing.Dict or dict in the Python

Tags: python

In the Python, dict and typing.Dict, I am seeing some information to say typing.Dict "Deprecated since version 3.9"

I am confused what I should choose dict or typing.Dict since Python 3.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dict`.
`typing.Dict` was created for allowing one to express the expected typing information in dictionaries before an update in the syntax of built-in classes itself (such as dict, list, set) would allow this to be expressed directly with the built-in classes.

The cost to remove the added classes in typing module is simply not worth doing in short-term, as it would render a lot of perfectly good Python code deprecated - but this should be expected to happen in a 10 year or so time-frame.

Comment: Does dict allow to use it like dict[str, int]

Comment: @joe you can do mixed type values.

Comment: yes. For this and similar Python doubts, I highly recommend you simply type the expressions in a Python interactive interpreter. The language offers it by default, and __all__ IDEs do offer a Python terminal where you can type this kind of expression and see the result imediatelly.

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
def foo(data: dict):
    print(data)
```

Comment: Does dict allow to use it like dict[str, int]

Comment: absolutely - it can